# my ARcore app start and crash immediately after when I launched it from android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arcore

after I launched my app from android studio to my OP 6 the app ask for the permission and crash at the same time.

I use Sceneform QuickStart and follow each step , but impossible to make it run

I already use AR apps on this phone before

I already try to restart from the beginning but I had the same problem

my manifest:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fr.maximedumas.firstscene">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <!-- Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 or later. -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />

    <!-- Indicates that app requires ARCore ("AR Required"). Ensures the app is
         visible only in the Google Play Store on devices that support ARCore.
         For "AR Optional" apps remove this line. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar"  android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

my gradle (app) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.maximedumas.firstscene"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.4.0'

    // Alternatively, use ArSceneView without the UX dependency.
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.12.0'
}


sceneform.asset('sampleData/earth.obj',
        'default',
        'sampleData/earth.sfa',
        'src/main/res/raw/earth')
```

here is my mainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    private static final double MIN_OPENGL_VERSION = 3.0;
    ArFragment arfragment;

    ModelRenderable earthRenderable;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker", "FutureReturnValueIgnored"})
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(this)) {
            return;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arfragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.scene_fragment);


    }

    public static boolean checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(final Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires Android N or later");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires Android N or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
            return false;
        }
        String openGlVersionString =
                ((ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                        .getDeviceConfigurationInfo()
                        .getGlEsVersion();
        if (Double.parseDouble(openGlVersionString) < MIN_OPENGL_VERSION) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 later");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            activity.finish();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just have to update my dependecies
```
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.4.0'
```

Comment: post your crash loge here